# Match double quotation mark following punctuation with regex in Python to split sentence

Tags: python, regex

I'm sure I'm just missing something, but my regex is a little rusty.

I have a well formatted text corpus and it came out of a SQLite DB that had each review as a row, which is fine and I wrote it out that way to a text file, so each review is a line followed by a new line character.

What I need to do is convert every sentence into a line to feed an iterator that expects sentences as lines that then feeds a model. The text is all professionally written and edited, so a simple regex that splits lines based on strings ending in [.!?] or [.!?] followed by a double quotation mark (") is actually sufficient. something like

```
re.split('(?<=[.!?]) +|((?<=[.!?])\")', text)
```

The lookbehind works for anything except ("). I've usually done regex mostly in R or Ruby and this is just making me feel dumb in the wee hours of Sunday night.

Example text:

“Trip-hop” eventually became a ’90s punchline, a music-press shorthand for “overhyped hotel lounge music.” But today, the much-maligned subgenre almost feels like a secret precedent. Listen to any of the canonical Bristol-scene albums of the mid-late ’90s, when the genre was starting to chafe against its boundaries, and you’d think the claustrophobic, anxious 21st century started a few years ahead of schedule.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Please give some examples of strings.

Comment: Try `r'(?:(?<=[.!?])|(?<=[.!?]"))\s+'`

Comment: Edited with first 3 examples sentences in the dataset.

This example, for instance, doesn't split on the first sentence that ends with a double quote after the period.

Comment: You use different kind of double quotes. Try using a character class [`[\"”]`.](https://regex101.com/r/8ui9GE/1/)

Comment: The different types of double quotes was the hang up. While that example worked in the regex tester perfectly, it didn't work using split(), though moving the \" outside the lookbehind worked, though it lopped off the quotation mark. Borrowing rom both suggestions with modification, this got it done: `re.split('(?:(?<=[.!?]) +|(?<=[.!?][\"”]) +)', text)`

Comment: @JasonThomas My suggestion is working well even when you need to support curly double quotes, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
r'(?:(?<=[.!?])|(?<=[.!?]["”]))\s+'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K86Gfm/2)

**Details**

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing alternation group matching:

  - `(?<=[.!?])` - a position that is immediately preceded with `.`, `!` or `?`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<=[.!?]["”])` - a position that is immediately preceded with `.`, `!` or `?` followed with `"` or `”`
- `)` - end of the grouping
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces.

[Python 2 demo](http://rextester.com/RGBRJ61576):

```
import re
rx = ur'(?:(?<=[.!?])|(?<=[.!?]["”]))\s+'
s = u"“Trip-hop” eventually became a ’90s punchline, a music-press shorthand for “overhyped hotel lounge music.” But today, the much-maligned subgenre almost feels like a secret precedent. Listen to any of the canonical Bristol-scene albums of the mid-late ’90s, when the genre was starting to chafe against its boundaries, and you’d think the claustrophobic, anxious 21st century started a few years ahead of schedule."
for result in re.split(rx, s):
    print(result.encode("utf-8"))
```

Output:

```
“Trip-hop” eventually became a ’90s punchline, a music-press shorthand for “overhyped hotel lounge music.”

But today, the much-maligned subgenre almost feels like a secret precedent.

Listen to any of the canonical Bristol-scene albums of the mid-late ’90s, when the genre was starting to chafe against its boundaries, and you’d think the claustrophobic, anxious 21st century started a few years ahead of schedule.
```